# React not updating varibles

Tags: reactjs, mqtt

I'm trying to make a small webpage for a project. I use an esp32 to send a payload with MQTT. I want to show this message on a react app. but my postboxStatus doesn't update in my but if I console log it I can see that I updated it.

```
function Main() {

    var postboxStatus = "empty"

    const mqtt = require('mqtt')

    const host = 'test.mosquitto.org'
    const port = '1883'
    const clientId = `mqtt_${Math.random().toString(16).slice(3)}`
    
    const connectUrl = `mqtt://${host}:${port}`
    const client = mqtt.connect(connectUrl, {
      clientId,
      clean: true,
      connectTimeout: 4000,
      username: 'randomUserName',
      password: '',
      reconnectPeriod: 1000,
    })
    
    const topic = 'random/topic'
    client.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected')
      client.subscribe([topic], () => {
        console.log(`Subscribe to topic '${topic}'`)
      })
      client.publish(topic, 'nodejs mqtt test', { qos: 0, retain: false }, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error)
        }
      })
    })
    client.on('message', (topic, payload) => {
      console.log('Received Message:', topic, payload.toString())
      postboxStatus = payload.toString();
    })



  return (
    <div>
        <h1> {postboxStatus} </h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: This is what state is for. (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). A function component is called each render, meaning all variables are reset. You need state to persist values across renders.

Comment: I tried this but it won't update. I think it's because of this part. because it's in the function client.on('message', (topic, payload) => {       console.log('Received Message:', topic, payload.toString())       setPostboxStatus(payload.toString());     }) but not sure what this is called so not sure how to look for the solution
@BrianThompson

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just change the variable and expect that React will re-render it. You should use `useState()` [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for changing your state, like:

```
function Main() {
    const [postboxStatus, setPostboxStatus] = useState('empty');

    const mqtt = require('mqtt')

    const host = 'test.mosquitto.org'
    const port = '1883'
    const clientId = `mqtt_${Math.random().toString(16).slice(3)}`
    
    const connectUrl = `mqtt://${host}:${port}`
    const client = mqtt.connect(connectUrl, {
      clientId,
      clean: true,
      connectTimeout: 4000,
      username: 'randomUserName',
      password: '',
      reconnectPeriod: 1000,
    })
    
    const topic = 'random/topic'
    client.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected')
      client.subscribe([topic], () => {
        console.log(`Subscribe to topic '${topic}'`)
      })
      client.publish(topic, 'nodejs mqtt test', { qos: 0, retain: false }, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error)
        }
      })
    })
    client.on('message', (topic, payload) => {
      console.log('Received Message:', topic, payload.toString())
      setPostboxStatus(payload.toString());
    })



  return (
    <div>
        <h1> {postboxStatus} </h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: I tried this but it won't update. I think it's because of this part. because it's in the function 
`client.on('message', (topic, payload) => {
      console.log('Received Message:', topic, payload.toString())
      setPostboxStatus(payload.toString());
    })`
but not sure what this is called so not sure how to look for the solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the exact reason, but you can try to set the stringify payload into variable, and then set into the state, it may work.

```
client.on('message', (topic, payload) => {
  console.log('Received Message:', topic, payload.toString())
  const statusFromMessage = payload.toString();
  setPostboxStatus(statusFromMessage);
})
```